# passing data to query builder

Tags: php

I am using PHP and MySQL.

I had a form text field where in

```
<input type='text' name ='key' id='key' value = 'property5 = mobile'>
```

I try to pass this value to mysql query builder just appending this value to where clause, but it does not work because the value part does not have quotes around it. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are doing... but I am guessing by your post that you are trying to escape your data.

To do this, use the mysql_real_escape_string() function.  Documentation can be found at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php.

This will take your string and add all the appropriate escaping automatically.

Comment: you got my question wrong man. 

see this variable is like $_POST['key'] rite.. i try to pass this to a query like ... select * from table where $_POST['key']; but since 'mobile' which is the value is not quoted .it throws errors.

Comment: Pradeep, what you are doing is extremely dangerous.  If you do it like this, it is trivial to write some code that posts whatever I want to your script, and hijack your database.  You MUST escape any data coming from the user that you are using in your query.  Consider naming your input property5 and setting the value to mobile.  Then in your PHP, do your query like mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE property5=\"" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['property5']) . "\";")

Comment: so u mean to say i cannot directly pass key value pair directly .property5 = mobile. bcos the client wants a dynamic query builder..

Comment: If you MUST have a dynamic query builder client-side, then you need to break it down in such a way that the query is being generated server-side, not client-side.  Perhaps have an input on the page where they choose the field, a comparison, and then a value.  Then, validate the input and generate the query on your own in PHP.